# Do we use hash functions for anything 'critical' under the assumption that collisions will never occur?

Tags: hash, cryptography

I'm currently learning the basics of cryptography and started to wonder. I understand that if an attacker wanted to 'pretend to be you' they could theoretically find a collision for your password or whatever it may be that identifies you, then authenticate themselves with that hash value.

Are there any other less obvious uses for hash functions perhaps aside from information security where in the almost impossible off chance that a collision occurs something rather strange would happen? Or in fact are there any real world examples of when this has happened?

I wonder because from what I understand if we use a strong enough hash function we pretty much assume that a collision will certainly not happen... but what if it did? Do we ever use hash functions for anything 'critical'?

edit: This is purely a speculative question.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of try would be so huge (as the associated time to process) that the login by an unknown user is unlikely probable.

In order to prevent that king of attack, you can put some security like interval between 3 false tries. That done, the time needed to process the entire attack with a result would be too long for the attacker.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack.

The hashing method can also be used to create CheckSum, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum.

Comment: I understand how hash functions are used in day to day applications. Are there any examples of hash functions used outside of these cases?

Comment: @Titus Except cases listed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Description I don't know any other application.

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions are also used to digitally sign documents. Assume you have got a document like a PDF and you want your boss to sign it. You would send it to him, he would sign it and you could send it over to someone else in his name.

Or you could prepare a special document that abuses a hash collision. You do not necessarily need a full hash collision. MD5 for example applies block by block of plain text to the hash. If you can find a collision for this single block you won.

Lets say "asdasd" causes a collision with "qweqwe".

You can create a PDF like so:

```
Headline

if("asdasd" == "asdasd")
  Good text...
else
  Evil text...
```

Your boss will see "Good text...". After you have his digital signature for this document you replace one "asdasd" by "qweqwe".

```
Headline

if("asdasd" == "qweqwe")
  Good text...
else
  Evil text...
```

Now you can send the evil PDF with a valid signature.

It is not as easy as I described but you get the idea I think.

Comment: This "block by block" property is rooted in the [Merkle–Damgård construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle–Damgård_construction), which is also used by SHA1 and the SHA2 family. However, only MD5 has been broken in practice.